# MATLAB: Problem calling builtin('addlistener', ...)

Tags: matlab, event-listener, built-in

In a Matlab (2017b) class I'm trying to overload `addlistener` and have problems calling it using the `builtin` function.

I first thought the problem was caused by the class implementation, but it turns out that I'm able to reproduce the problem with a few lines of code:

```matlab
% This works ...
l = line(rand(2,1),rand(2,1));
addlistener(l,'Color','PostSet',@(h,e)disp(123));  % create listener
l.Color = rand(1,3);  % trigger listener, '123' is displayed

% This does not ...
builtin('addlistener',l,'Color','PostSet',@(h,e)disp(456)); % ERROR, but why !?
```

Using the `builtin` command in the last code line throws the following error:

```matlab
First argument provided is not valid for addlistener. (Check its type or
validity)
```

I think the syntax for `builtin` is correct and would think that this might  be a Matlab bug, but maybe someone can prove me wrong :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builtin function `addlistener` does not support objects of type `line`, you need the version that is overloaded for `line`. But you cannot call that version with `builtin`.

You likely are trying to call the superclass version of a method. To do so, follow the directions in the [manual](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/calling-superclass-methods-on-subclass-objects.html):

```
addlistener@superclass(args)
```

Comment: Hi Cris,
looking at your comment I was not able to fix the example above. However, it did help me to solve my problem in the original code, which I have not explicitly stated.
In my code I did not realize that `addlistener` was overloaded in the `handle` class and thought that I had to direct my call by using `builtin`. So, to fix this bug I followed your link and fixed the error by explicitly calling the superclass, as suggested:

`l = addlistener@handle(...)`

Thanks for pointing this out.
+1

Comment: @shoelz: Yes, my argument is that the example in the OP cannot be fixed. It is just not possible to do that. `builtin` is to call, for example, `size` for a class they overloads `size`. There exists a `size` that is not a class method and which works with objects of arbitrary type. `addlistener` is not like that.